# TypeScript extends types code not compiling

Tags: typescript

I understand what the following typescript error is saying although I don't understand why because the `A` type is extending `IReduxAction` and is specified elsewhere which also `extends IReduxAction`.

Any help here would be great.

Here is the error

```
Type '{ ACTION_NAME: IReducer<ISt, IAction<"hello", string>>; }' is not assignable to type 'TCaseFunctions<ISt>'.
  Property 'ACTION_NAME' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type 'IReducer<ISt, IAction<"hello", string>>' is not assignable to type '<A extends IReduxAction>(state: Readonly<ISt>, action: A) => ISt'.
      Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
        Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'IAction<"hello", string>'.
          Type 'IReduxAction' is not assignable to type 'IAction<"hello", string>'.
            Property 'payload' is missing in type 'IReduxAction'.
```

Here is the code. You can paste this directly into the playground at https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html

```
export interface IReduxAction {
  type: any
}

export interface IGenericAction<T, P, M> extends IReduxAction {
  type: T
  payload: P
  meta?: M
}

export interface IAction<T, P> extends IGenericAction<T, P, any> {}

export type IReducer<S, A extends IReduxAction> =
  (state: Readonly<S>, action: A) => S

export type TCaseFunctions<S> = {
  [action: string]: <A extends IReduxAction>(state: Readonly<S>, action: A) => S
}

interface ISt { a: string }

type MyAction = IAction<'hello', string>
const basicAction: IReduxAction = {
  type: 'foo'
}

const reducer: IReducer<ISt, MyAction> = (state, action) => state
const caseFunctions: TCaseFunctions<ISt> = {
  ACTION_NAME: reducer
}
const rootReducer = createReducer<ISt>(caseFunctions)
// rootReducer(state, { type: 'hello', payload: 'foobar' })
```

Answer (score 0):

`TCaseFunction` is defined as having a generic function signature, so when calling, any action can be passed in:

```
caseFunction({} as ISt, {} as MyAction)
caseFunction({} as ISt, {} as MyOtherAction)
```

The function you try to assign to `caseFunction` is not generic, it takes a specific action (`MyAction`) so it does not respect the contract `TCaseFunction` defines.

You could add the generic parameter of the signature to `TCaseFunction` and then things would work as expected:

```
export type TCaseFunction<S, A> = (state: Readonly<S>, action: A) => S 
const caseFunction: TCaseFunction<ISt, MyAction> = reducer
```

**Edit**

A bit more details on why generic functions are not compatible with non generic functions. Consider the following example:

```
type genericFunction = <A>(param: A) => A;

let ok:genericFunction = function <A>( param: A) { return param};
// We can pass to the function any type A
ok(1); // be it int
ok(""); // or string 

let notOk:genericFunction = function (param: string ){ return param.substr(1);}
// The above assignment is not allowed because the signature for genericFunction mandates that it be able to handle any A not just a specific A
// genericFunction  allows either of these:
notOk(""); // We can pass a string, as the implementation expects
notOk(1); // but we can pass an int, which the implementation would not know how to process
```

**Edit2**

In your case you don't appear to actually care what `A` is, just that it is an action, you can use the following definition taht will force all members to be functions with the second parameter being any IReduxAction:

```
export type TCaseFunctions<S> = {
    [action: string]: (state: Readonly<S>, action: IReduxAction) => S;
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your help :o) - `TCaseFunction` has specified that `action` should extend `IReduxAction` so I thought this means that the object passed in must have a `type` property. Unfortunately my example is simplified slightly and I don't type each case function individually, they are part of an object where the actions are all different and so need to be dynamic.

Comment: @DaveTaylor could you update your question with an example closer to your use case ? I can only answer the question that is asked, if you add more info I can see what we can do in that case

Comment: @DaveTaylor The same problem persists, `reducer` is not generic, the interface mandates a generic function. What do you want to do with `caseFunction`? Do you want to be able to call `caseFunction.ACTION_NAME(...)` or is it going to be dynamically accessed by string ?

Comment: Thanks for your continued help :o) I must be misunderstanding why it isn't generic. I'm expecting the action type to be generic because of `<A extends IReduxAction>` and then `action: A`. Ultimately I was hoping to ensure that the function's action parameter type should be an object with *at least* at `type: string` property but allow other properties to exist

Comment: I've added more detail showing how it is used to create a root reducer function which calls the appropriate inner reducer based on the type property

Comment: @DaveTaylor I added more details, hope it helps

Comment: thanks, I had the type of `action: IReduxAction` originally but was getting an error that `MyAction` was not compatible with `IReduxAction` because `IReduxAction` does not have a `payload` property.